# Size-classes Autolayout Some UIStackViews are hidden for CwRh

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, ios-autolayout, size-classes

[image: UIStackViews Are Hidden]

As I have applied SizeClasses for HrWc but when i used these size classes   for HcWr some of UIStackViews are hidden, as shown as in image. can anyone help me to sort out this, why this happening.

Comment: So you have specified that these views are available only for a specific size class combination and you are wondering why they are not available in a completely different size class combination?

Comment: @WarrenBurton thanks so we can create for particular size classes?

Comment: That is what you said you did in your question. The effect you are seeing is correct behaviour.